# I cannot understand the reasoning for the math in this code?

Tags: arduino, sensors

This is the code provided by Seead for a simple analoge sound level sensor?

I understand the code but not the reasoning for sampling for 32 reads?

```
    const int pinAdc = A0;
    
    void setup()
    {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    //Serial.println("Grove - Sound Sensor Test...");
    }
    
    void loop()
    {
    long sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<32; i++)
    {
        sum += analogRead(pinAdc);
    }

    sum >>= 5;

    Serial.println(sum);
    delay(10);
    }
```

Comment: I answered just before you edited, is your question about the averaging? or why it's averaging over 32 samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doing an average over 32 readings.

Step 1, sum 32 readings.

Step 2, bit shift right by 5.

Shifting right is equivalent to dividing by 2. So 2^5 = 32. So it's equivalent of dividing by 32.

Comment: Thanks, now I get the 32 I was try various maths as I thought it captured a certain length of time based.

Comment: always be suspicious of powers of 2 :) Yeah there's nothing interesting in terms of time, because it's just doing a rudimentary loop. if it was trying to do something precise, it would use timer interrupts or something similar to do the sampling